# Disable npm warning during package installation

Tags: node.js, terminal, dependencies, npm

I get this warning during "npm install -g FooBarModule" on Terminal OSX

```
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/express.io requires express@'~3.4.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/express,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 4.8.5
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-meanjs/node_modules/yeoman-generator requires chalk@'^0.4.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-meanjs/node_modules/chalk,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.5.1
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-meanjs/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/file-utils requires glob@'~3.2.6' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-meanjs/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/glob,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 4.0.5
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/meanio/node_modules/bower/node_modules/bower-json requires graceful-fs@'~2.0.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/meanio/node_modules/bower/node_modules/graceful-fs,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 3.0.2
```

How avoid it ?

Thanks !

Comment: Perhaps a version error with the required packages...what version of express are you using?

Comment: The lastest version of express